# smooth video progress bar update javascript

Tags: javascript, html, sass

I have a custom video progress bar on my site which is working well.
But the progression update is jumping between values and I'm trying to smooth it.

HTML:

```
<video id ="myVideo">
 <source src="myvideo.mp4">
</video>

<div class="progress">
  <div class="timeElapsed"></div>
</div>
```

SASS:

```
.progress
  width: 100%
  height: 8px
  background: #fff
  position: absolute
  bottom: 0
  .timeElapsed
    position: absolute
    height: 100%
    width: 0%
    background: #000
```

JS:

```
var myVideo = document.querySelector('#myVideo'),
    progress = document.querySelector('.progress'),
    timeElapsed = document.querySelector('.timeElapsed'),
    duration,
    percentage,
    currentTime;

myVideo.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(){
  duration = myVideo.duration
  currentTime = myVideo.currentTime
  percentage = (100 /duration) * currentTime
  timeElapsed.style.width = percentage + '%'
})
```

When I console.log(percentage) in my timeupdate event, I have this output :

```
0.14095513960976902
0.3264236667597889
0.6970909117642735
1.0636110335092854
1.2511968652129803
1.435445001543868
1.79435606004911
1.9811530487715225
2.1658047962829547
2.532771904544853
2.7182242578406437
```

With this result and the way it's displayed in the console I know that I'm missing something but I don't know what, any solution here ?

Comment: I would use JQuery animations for this, it does the hard work of smoothing things for you. The other option is to update more often, at regular intervals, while making sure that the progress reported is granular enough.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to `.timeElapsed` a transition. For example, `transition: 100ms`